# R cumulative sum in dynamic data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'M1'=c(1,20,3,4,50))
```

Now I want to create an additional 179 columns (M2 - M180) which is dependent on the sum of previous Mx columns. For instance, M2 should be the sum for all previous Mx values i.e. M1 in this case. And M3 should be the sum M1+M2 and so on all the way to M180.

The expected result for the first three Mx columsn should be:

```
Expected_res <- data.frame('a'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'M1'=c(1,20,3,4,50), 'M2'=c(1,20,3,4,50), 'M3'=c(2,40,6,8,100))
```

Basically I want the excel equivalent to Sum($E1:E1) and then dragging it out for 180 columns, for each row of course.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop :

```
for(i in 2:180) {
  df[paste0('M', i)] <- rowSums(df[-1])
}
```

`-1` ignores the 1st column (`a`) and takes sum of all other columns to create a new column.

Here's the output of first 5 columns.

```
df
#  a M1 M2  M3  M4  M5
#1 1  1  1   2   4   8
#2 2 20 20  40  80 160
#3 3  3  3   6  12  24
#4 4  4  4   8  16  32
#5 5 50 50 100 200 400
```

Answer (score 0):

using `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame('a'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'M1'=c(1,20,3,4,50))
n <- 5
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(seq_len(n), ~transmute(df, !!paste0("M", .x + 1) := M1 * 2 ^ (.x - 1))))
#>   a M1 M2  M3  M4  M5  M6
#> 1 1  1  1   2   4   8  16
#> 2 2 20 20  40  80 160 320
#> 3 3  3  3   6  12  24  48
#> 4 4  4  4   8  16  32  64
#> 5 5 50 50 100 200 400 800
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame('a'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'M1'=c(1,20,3,4,50))
setDT(df)
n <- 5
col_names <- paste0("M", seq_len(n) + 1)
df[, (col_names) := lapply(seq_len(n), function(x) M1 * 2 ^ (x - 1))]
df
#>    a M1 M2  M3  M4  M5  M6
#> 1: 1  1  1   2   4   8  16
#> 2: 2 20 20  40  80 160 320
#> 3: 3  3  3   6  12  24  48
#> 4: 4  4  4   8  16  32  64
#> 5: 5 50 50 100 200 400 800
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>